# Intent filter still getting called,even if the app is killed

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have been using Intent filter for receiving the sms ,as the sms is received i'm displaying the `toast message` ,but the thing is **broadcast receiver is still executing even if the app is in killed?**.I just want the app to be display the toasts when the app is either in the foreground or the background,yeah **i want in the background too** .And also is there a way ,i programatically kill the broadcast receiver as well as  programatically start it.

Comment: how u can say app is killed..? if u removed from recent..it is still in memory...u can check this..by forcefully kill app from app manager and try this again.

Comment: yeah i did the same as you said and killed the app

Comment: Good.  The intent filters are working as they should do!  Imagine sharing an attachment in an email.  It would be pretty useless if you could only share with loaded applications.  For stopping the BroadcastReceiver, what's wrong with `unregisterReceiver`?